# Function does not have a full prototype compiler error

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to access the following function

```
     err = SetupForFlash();
```

That function is written in blackfin.c

```
ERROR_CODE SetupForFlash(void)
{   
    unsigned imask_value;

    imask_value = cli();                /* disable interrupts */ 

    /* set clock multiplier and CCLK and SCLK divider */
    *pSIC_IWR |= 0x0001;                /* enable PLL wakeup */
    *pPLL_DIV  = ((CCLK_DIVIDER & 0x3) << 4) | (SCLK_DIVIDER & 0xF); 
    *pPLL_CTL  = (CLOCK_MULTIPLIER << 9) & 0x7E00;    /* set new clock multplier */
    ssync();
    idle();                             /* wait until PLL settle down */

    /* enable async memory banks and defines timing/waitstate */ 
    *pEBIU_AMBCTL0 = 0x7bb07bb0;
    *pEBIU_AMBCTL1 = 0xffc27bb0;
    *pEBIU_AMGCTL  = 0x000f;            /* enable all external memory banks */

    /* */    
    sti(imask_value);                   /* enable interrupts */

    return NO_ERR;
}
```

The prototype is in blackfin.h as follows

```
ERROR_CODE SetupForFlash(void);
```

I use that function in irq_software.c
I include the header blackfin.h which has the prototype
but I get a warning that the function does not have a full prototype

here is the header of the blackfin.h

```
#ifndef __ERRORS_H__
#define __ERRORS_H__

// enum of possible errors
typedef enum
{
        NO_ERR,
        POLL_TIMEOUT,
        VERIFY_WRITE,
        INVALID_SECTOR,
        INVALID_BLOCK,
        UNKNOWN_COMMAND,
        PROCESS_COMMAND_ERR,
        NOT_READ_ERROR,
        DRV_NOTAT_BREAK,
        BUFFER_IS_NULL,
        NUM_ERROR_CODES,
}ERROR_CODE;


// function prototypes
ERROR_CODE SetupForFlash(void);
ERROR_CODE GetCodes(void);
ERROR_CODE PollToggleBit(unsigned long ulOffset);
ERROR_CODE ResetFlash(void);
ERROR_CODE EraseFlash(void);
ERROR_CODE EraseBlock( int nBlock );
ERROR_CODE UnlockFlash(unsigned long ulOffset);
ERROR_CODE WriteData( unsigned long ulStart, long lCount, long lStride, int *pnData );
ERROR_CODE FillData( unsigned long ulStart, long lCount, long lStride, int *pnData );
ERROR_CODE ReadData( unsigned long ulStart, long lCount, long lStride, int *pnData );
ERROR_CODE ReadFlash( unsigned long ulOffset, int *pnValue );
ERROR_CODE WriteFlash( unsigned long ulOffset, int nValue );
ERROR_CODE GetSectorNumber( unsigned long ulOffset, int *pnSector );
ERROR_CODE GetSectorStartEnd( long *lStartOff, long *lEndOff, int nSector );


#endif // __ERRORS_H__
```

Comment: Is `ERROR_CODE` defined?

Comment: yes its defined in the .h in blackfin .h

Comment: why negative my question!! without any comment

Comment: Is `ERROR_CODE` defined before or after `SetupForFlash()`?

Comment: its defined before SetupForFlash(); in the .h blackfin.h

Comment: Try put the definition of `ERROR_CODE` and the prototype directly before the function. Can you show us the definition of `ERROR_CODE`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I added the header file, please talk a look

Comment: Possibly `__ERRORS_H__` is defined by a system include. Test with `__MYERRORS_H__`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it works, thanks. Please add it as answer :)

Comment: Glad to have been of help :-)

Comment: If that is not a system header: names starting with single or double underscore are reserved for implementation use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly `__ERRORS_H__` is defined by a system include. Test with `__MYERRORS_H__`.

Comment: One should generally avoid writing compiler guards that begin with an underscore. Note the C standard 7.1.3: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: @Lundin, can a preprocessor name be considered an "identifier"? (Your comment is further valid! Avoid underscores in names.)

Comment: I don't think C has much of a formal definition of the term "identifier". 6.2.1 seems to be the closest thing to a formal definition: "**An identifier can denote** an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or
enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; **a macro name; or a macro parameter**."